# Use Subprocess in a form action of a template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

In a form action in a template, is there a way to run script ?

```
     <form action="{% subprocess.check_call(['python', 'myFile.py']) %}" method="post">
<input class="btn_ok" type="submit" value="Validate" />

       </form>
```

Comment: The "action" attribute of an HTML form is the url the form should be submitted to (if different from the current url). And given how non-sensical your question is (for someone that knows how this works I mean) I strongly suggest you learn how the HTTP protocol works and the difference between frontend and backend code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. I did not use subprocess. 
The reason why i ask the question that i posted it's because i would like to know in the same index page, how to take the code of a meeting in my app without redirect in another template.

In the urls.py of my app, i mentioned the path:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]
```

In my template i have a list of meetings that i took by a query-set; by using a block {% for item in m_list_key %}. I created a small form (with submit button) inside the iteration "for" :

```
<form action="/meetingPage/" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="hidden" value="{{ item.codeMeeting }}" id="code_meet" name="codeMeeting_name" />
   <input class="btnParticipate" type="submit" value="Participate" />
</form>
```

In the views.py of my app **meetingPage**, the index function is :

```
 def index(request):
        meetings = Meeting.objects.all()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            the_code_meeting = request.POST['codeMeeting_name']
            return render(request, 'meetingPage/index.html',{'code_meeting_key': the_code_meeting,'m_list_key': meetings }) 
        return render(request, 'meetingPage/index.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that doesn't really make any sense.

The action has to be a string with a URL you want the action to happen at.

What you should instead do is make a view that does whatever processing you're trying to do in `myFile.py`, or have the view run subprocess and run that file, if you really must.

Comment: In the action form i would not like to call a url. Can you give me an example please?

Comment: There is no example. The form has to call a URL. There is nothing else it can possibly do.

Comment: Have you read through the docs here? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/